# WooCommerce Rest API Create Order doesn't fires Emails

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am having problems with WooCommerce in the latest version. Every time a order is created and updated to processing, WooCommerce isn't firing the New Order Mail. I found a solution here from 2020 but it isn't working.

Anyone had the same problem and found a solution for this? I also tried with a new installation on a different server, but the same problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about Order actions ? Did you test to fire email trough there ? I would think its more server related issue maybe contact your hosting and ask to check if emails are blocked ?

Comment: Emails working. It's no hosting issue. Normal orders are processed as expected. Only API created orders aren't firing mails.

Comment: Check the email settings and make sure email is enabled. Then check the **Recipient's Email** address and make sure your **Sender Email/Email From** and **Recipient's Email** are not the same, sometimes Mailer will mark those as SPAM. Then also check for fatal error log in `WooCommerce > Status > Log` then also enable debug log and check the `debug.log` file and see if you have something there that is related to this issue.